# Prove that limiting distribution is uniform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, uniform-distribution, monte-carlo

Denote $S_n$ as set of all strings of length $n$ with elements from 4 symbol alphabet [A,G,T,C].

I have Markov Chain that picks one element in previous string $s_i$ uniformly and changes it to uniformly picked letter from alphabet.

How can i prove that limiting distribution of this chain will be uniform distribution from $S_n$?

Comment: It depends on what you are allowed to assume as already known.  You seem to have a finite-state irreducible aperiodic positive-recurrent Markov Chain where the uniform distribution over the $4^n$ states can be shown to be a stationary distribution, and therefore is the unique limiting distribution

Comment: @Henry how can i show that uniform distribution over the $4^n$ is stationary, if i know that markov chain is irreducible,aperiodic and positive-recurrent?

Comment: By symmetry: each state can be reached from and can lead to exactly $3n$ others in a single change, all with equal probability

Comment: So the transition matrix is symmetric, hence doubly stochastic. Thus, the unique stationary distribution is uniform.